# How do i display the Collapse Menus checkbox in a Python menu?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

The right click Header menu at the header is a C menu. I want to display the content in a Python menu. Like the View menu of the Text editor.

I can grab the operator, create my own class to execute it. And that way i can display the Flip to Top button. And it is fully functional. But how do i display the Collapse Menus prop with its checkbox? layout.operator is functional, but doesn't display the checkbox state. And layout.prop gives errors since i execute an operator, and don't have a prop involved here yet.

My problem is how the things needs to be connected, how the prop should look like. I cannot create a new prop here, it already exists. Or am i at the wrong track here? Maybe there is a direct way to grab this prop? As told it's a C menu, not Python.

The vital code parts are also marked green in the following screenshot:

```
class VIEW3D_MT_testheaderflip(bpy.types.Operator):
"""tooltip"""
bl_idname = "view3d.headerflip"
bl_label = "header flip"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

def execute(self, context):        # execute()
    bpy.ops.screen.header_flip()
    return {'FINISHED'}  
...

layout.operator("view3d.headerflip", text="headerflip")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**`Area.show_menus`**

Came across the property via @Leander comment on [Get topbar area instance to toggle menus](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146815/get-topbar-area-instance-to-toggle-menus)

[image]

Here it is appended to the view menu of the text editor. *Notice it flitters top to bottom of menu when used*

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    area = context.area
    layout.prop(area, "show_menus")
    
bpy.types.TEXT_MT_view.append(draw)
```

**Operator**

<strike>Not sure how to expose the property that indicates whether the header region menu is collapsed or not. You can however</strike>  add the [`bpy.ops.screen.header_toolbox()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.header_toolbox) operator to the view menu.  This is the header menu that pops up when right clicking in Header.

Notice I've appended / prepended to the view menu class, rather than, (.. the slippery  slope of), editing the UI py.

```
import bpy


def header_toolbox(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    #layout.operator("screen.header_flip")
    layout.operator("screen.header_toolbox")

# prepend to 3d view view menu
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.prepend(header_toolbox)
# append text editor view menu
bpy.types.TEXT_MT_view.append(header_toolbox)
```

Answer (score -1):

is you want A REAL CHECKBOX you must have a property and use the  "prop" option in layouts or columns:

example:

```
rd = context.scene.render            
layout.prop(rd, "use_overwrite")
```

or with columm:

```
rd = context.scene.render
split = layout.split()
col = split.column()
col.prop(rd, "use_overwrite")
```

[image: p1]
[image: p2]

*----------------------------------------------------------

if you see the properties option use another trick, use icons;

actually isn't a real checkbox, is only a icon that you can change:

[image: icon]

you should use something like:

```
layout.operator("view3d.headerflip", text="headerflip", icon="CHECKBOX_DEHLT")
```

in order to choose one specific icon, you must activate the "development icons addon"

[image: development icons]

Comment: Thanks yhoyo. The problem is, this specific menu item is not a prop, and it's in a C menu. layout.prop will not work here. Just layout.operator seems to do the trick. But without the checkbox.