# How to redraw status bar in Blender 2.80

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, workspaces

I've added my own progress bar to the Blender 2.80 status bar (the footer of Blender) with the following abstracted code:

```py
def draw_progress_bar(self, context):
    self.layout.prop(context.scene, "my_progress", text="Simulating")

bpy.types.STATUSBAR_HT_header.append(draw_progress_bar)
```

Only problem is, when I update the `my_progress` scene property, the progress bar in the UI doesn't update unless I move my mouse over the area. Typically, this would be solved by running the following code to redraw the area:

```py
def tag_redraw_areas(area_types:iter=["ALL"]):
    """ run tag_redraw for given area types """
    area_types = confirm_list(area_types)
    screens = [bpy.context.screen] if bpy.context.screen else bpy.data.screens
    for screen in screens:
        for area in screen.areas:
            for area_type in area_types:
                if area_type == "ALL" or area.type == area_type:
                    area.tag_redraw()
```

But in this case, the Status Bar does not seem to be listed in `bpy.context.screen.areas`. Is there any other way to redraw the status bar in Blender 2.80?

Answer (score 1):

I've found you can cause the status bar to redraw by calling:

`bpy.context.workspace.status_text_set_internal(None)`

It will of course also remove any currently set custom status text, but unlike the non 'internal' version it does not remove appended draw functions.

Comment: Hi & Any ideas re https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146815/getting-the-topbar-area-instance