# Is it possible to save a preference for not showing the Menus in the Startup file?

Tags: interface, customization

I work on a small laptop and find the Menu Tabs (File, Edit, Render, Etc) prevent some of the Workspace Tabs from showing.  I've found the Headers>Show Menu check box, but its annoying having to click click it every time I open the program.  Saving a new Startup File with the checkbox cleared doesn't preserve this particular preference.  Is there a way to hide the Menu Tabs by default?

Comment: Related  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146815/get-topbar-area-instance

Comment: @Leander IMO your suggestion in comment to link above would make good answer here.

Comment: @Leander, your suggested change to show_menus at line 209 results in ALL menus at top not displaying.  Same result if "if" clause of block directly below is deleted.  Further suggestions?