# How to customize the top bar of the 3D viewport

Tags: interface

I'd like to change the order of instruments on this toolbar (see the image attached). I'd like to bring blenderKit to the right corner and move all the shader options from the right corner to the center. Is it possible to do so?

I really need the shader and gizmo options in the center. I work on a small screen and if I add any extra editor type (like UV or image editor) they become hidden behind the outliner.
[image]

Comment: If you hold the mouse wheel down over the toolbar you can drag the whole toolbar left and right with the mouse which might help. This applies to all the Blender toolbars that are wider than their window.

Comment: Can also collapse the menus. (_View, Select, Add, Mesh, etc_)  Right click in a blank part of menu, Header menu, uncheck show menus.  Why I asked this somewhat related question  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146815/get-topbar-area-instance-to-toggle-menus  _ie_ can collapse most area type menus and save to start up file, to have them collapsed by default, however AFAIK cannot do this with topbar.